# Adobe illustrator - Save for Web function truncates all anchor points to integers (no decimals)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design

I'm using Adobe Illustrator Cloud CC to save a vector illustration to web.

The issue I have is that when I save for web, the polygon's (which I saved as URL) anchor points which all have decimal numbers are truncated to just integer which distorts the image.. when I copy the coordinates and plot them in Tableau or Excel..

Is there any way to just export the original (X,Y)s without truncation?

I've included an extract below, the numbers are all in integers..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had that issue as well. Here’s how to fix it.

The issue is the number of decimal places set when saving. As you’ve noted, Illustrator can round positions to less precision. That makes SVGs a little bit smaller, but it can utterly ruin user interface artwork.

The maximum is 7 decimal places, and I’ve found that to be enough for all the situations I’ve come across. I think 3 is the default, and it is not enough for most icons.

#### Save As

If you’re using Save As, the Decimal Places setting can be altered after you choose a location to save the file.

[image: Save As SVG settings in Adobe Illustrator]

#### Export As

If you’re using Export As, the Decimal setting can be altered after you choose a location to save the file.

[image: Export As settings in Adobe Illustrator]

#### Export for Screens

If you’re using Export for Screens, the Decimal setting can be altered be clicking the little cog icon on the right hand side of the window.

[image: Export for Screens SVG decimal places in Adobe Illustrator]

[image: Export for Screens SVG decimal places in Adobe Illustrator]

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, would there be something similar for Export -> Save for Web(Legacy) option?

Comment: Basically, what I need are the <Polygon ID: 234.3434, 333.563 ... ...> instead of <Path ID: > ..

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand. Do you want the shape to only contain straight line segments?

Comment: No, I would like to export curves as well. But the way its going to be done in polygon is with densification of the anchor points I believe.. is that correct?